# ZIO: Why RejectedExecutionException are being thrown?

Tags: multithreading, scala, executorservice, zio

I'm getting RejectedExecutionException while running following code:

```
override def run(args: List[String]): ZIO[zio.ZEnv, Nothing, ExitCode] = {
    val test = for {
      start  <- ZIO effect Instant.now.toEpochMilli
      loop   = for {
        f <- effectBlocking{Thread sleep 1000}
      } yield ()
      allFib <- loop.fork replicateM 2000
      _      <- Fiber joinAll allFib
      end    <- ZIO effect Instant.now.toEpochMilli
      _      <- putStrLn(s"Total time: ${end-start}")
    } yield ()

    test
      .catchAll(ZIO succeed _.getMessage)
      .map(_ => ExitCode.success)
  }
```

What am I doing wrong? When I execute the code below (I think it's more or less the same thing I'm trying to do on ZIO), using pure Scala and Futures, everything works fine without any exception.

```
  val tasks = new ListBuffer[Future[Unit]]
  
  for(_ <- 0 to 2000) {
    tasks += Future {
      Thread.sleep(1000)
    }
  }

  Await.result(Future sequence tasks, Duration.Inf)
```

With ZIO, I also tried to pass a dedicated ExecutorService, but it didn't work either.

Comment: Judging by code in `zio/blocking/package.scala`, they are using a pool with maximum of 1000 threads for `effectBlocking`. Your code requires twice that much. You might wanna override the executor specifically with `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` - I dunno how to do that exactly in ZIO.

Comment: @OlegPyzhcov I tried to use a dedicated ExecutionService (fixed and cached), but without success so far. Anyway, I believe that every ThreadPool has a "mailbox" (task queue), so that when all threads are busy, new tasks are stored in the queue.

Comment: But... by somehow if I replace effectBlocking with a normal effect, it works! But i don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

Modern effect types promote use of two thread pools in the app, one for thread-blocking stuff (recommended size is unbounded, but as we learned, ZIO limits the size to 1000), another for computation (ZIO is `2*CPU hyperthreads`; in cats-effect it's `min(2, CPU hyperthreads)`) and things that may block but not for much that it's worth caring about, like `println`.

In ZIO, `effectBlocking` is how you tell the execution to switch to that other pool. This is important to do for non-insignificant blocking, because NOT doing so starves the compute pool, on which the rest of your app is running.

That's why `ZIO.effect` works - it uses the compute pool. For me your code would finish in ~250s (4 cores means 8 threads, and we have 2000 sleeping for a second).

---

Now, I'm going to assume that you have replaced wrong threadpool with a cached one, since this works:

```scala
object ZioBlockingTest extends zio.App {

  val cachedBlocker = ZLayer.succeed(new Blocking.Service {
    override def blockingExecutor: Executor =
      Executor.fromExecutionContext(Int.MaxValue)(
        ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool())
      )
  })


  override def run(args: List[String]): ZIO[ZEnv, Nothing, ExitCode] = {
    val test = for {
      start  <- ZIO effect Instant.now.toEpochMilli
      loop   = for {
        f <- effectBlocking{Thread sleep 1000}
      } yield ()
      allFib <- loop.fork replicateM 2000
      _      <- Fiber joinAll allFib
      end    <- ZIO effect Instant.now.toEpochMilli
      _      <- putStrLn(s"Total time: ${end-start}")
    } yield ()

    test
      .catchAll(ZIO succeed _.getMessage)
      .map(_ => ExitCode.success)
  }.provideSomeLayer[ZEnv](cachedBlocker) // <-- override the pool used for effectBlocking
}
```

This finishes in slightly under 2s for me, due to overhead of spinning up and joining 2000 actual OS threads.

---

**P.S.** you are right about thread pool having "mailboxes" but the mailboxes themselves can be different. Computation pools usually use `java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockedQueue` with maximum capacity (`Int.MaxValue`) so stuff can always be postponed for when there's a free thread. Blocking pools use `j.u.c.SynchronousQueue` which basically has a capacity of 0, so it's "start immediately or die". It can probably be considered a bug in ZIO that it uses both limited thread pool and `SynchronousQueue` for blocking tasks.

---

**P.P.S.** `Futures` are using some thread pool too, but you've probably imported `ExecutionContext.Implicits.global`. It has a bit of extra magic that you can use to tell the pool "I'm blocking here, maybe add some threads":

```scala
  for(_ <- 0 to 2000) {
    tasks += Future {
      blocking { Thread.sleep(1000) }
    }
  }
```

The exact limits of global EC are configurable with VM properties; default for additional threads in case of blocking is 256. That makes example code finish in few seconds (still slower than using ZIO with a proper cached pool).

Lazy effect types don't rely on this sort of thing since if you use two pools right, it's actually more performant; and it's less hard to use different pools since the aren't passed as `implicit` everywhere.